# Symbolic math simplification in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am trying to do a symbolic computation using MATLAB. The code is as follows

```
clc; 
syms jx1 jx2 jx3 jx4 jy1 jy2 jy3 jy4 jz1 jz2 jz3 jz4;
A=[1 1 1 1;jx1 jx2 jx3 jx4;jy1 jy2 jy3 jy4;jz1 jz2 jz3 jz4] 
J=inv(A);
simple(J);
```

Now I want to introduce the following notations to simplify

```
jx12=jx1-jx2; jx13=jx1-jx3; jx14=jx1-jx4;
jx23=jx2-jx3; jx24=jx2-jx4; jx34=jx3-jx4;
jy12=jy1-jy2; jy13=jy1-jy3; jy14=jy1-jy4; jy23=jy2-jy3; jy24=jy2-jy4; 
jy34=jy3-jy4;jz12=jz1-jz2; jz13=jz1-jz3; jz14=jz1-jz4; jz23=jz2-jz3; jz24=jz2-jz4; jz34=jz3-jz4;
jx21=-jx12; jx31=-jx13; jx41=-jx14; jx32=-jx23; jx42=-jx24; jx43=-jx34;
jy21=-jy12; jy31=-jy13; jy41=-jy14; jy32=-jy23; jy42=-jy24; jy43=-jy34;
jz21=-jz12; jz31=-jz13; jz41=-jz14; jz32=-jz23; jz42=-jz24; jz43=-jz34;
```

and further simplify the expression for `inv` in terms of the above.

I have also used the `assume` command like `assume(jx12==jx1-jx2)` but I am unable to get the answer in terms of the new symbols.

How should I go about this?